# Apriori Algorithm gives memory locations

Tags: java, algorithm, weka

I have my application which need to get associations via the **Apriori Algorithm**. In order to achieve results I use **Weka** dependency. Though I want to get associations it prints memory locations. I have attached the output as well. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
public class App 
{
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    public static BufferedReader readDataFile(String filename) {
        BufferedReader inputReader = null;

        try {
            inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        }
        return inputReader;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        //Define ArrayList to Add Clustered Information
        ArrayList<FastVector[]> associationInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<FastVector[]>();
        Apriori apriori = new Apriori();
        apriori.setNumRules(15);
        BufferedReader datafile = readDataFile("/media/jingi_ingi/IR1_CPRA_X6/Documents/ss.arff");
        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);
        //   Instances instances = new Instances(datafile);
        apriori.buildAssociations(data);
        log.debug("Testing Apriori Algo Results Started ....");
        log.debug("-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-");
        log.debug("Number of Associations : " + apriori.getNumRules());
        log.debug("Adding Association Information to ArrayList ..");

        Object objectArrayOfAssociations[] = new Object[apriori.getNumRules()];
                        log.debug(apriori.getAllTheRules().toString());

       for(int i=0; i<apriori.getNumRules(); i++) {
            objectArrayOfAssociations[i] = apriori.getAllTheRules();
            log.debug("Associations Discovered : " + objectArrayOfAssociations[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the Application:

> 2015-04-05 20:16:42 DEBUG App:48 - Associations Discovered :
>   [Lweka.core.FastVector;@19a96bae
>
> 2015-04-05 20:16:42 DEBUG App:48 - Associations Discovered :
>   [Lweka.core.FastVector;@19a96bae
>
> 2015-04-05 20:16:42 DEBUG App:48 - Associations Discovered :
>   [Lweka.core.FastVector;@19a96bae
>
> 2015-04-05 20:16:42 DEBUG App:48 - Associations Discovered :
>   [Lweka.core.FastVector;@19a96bae

Answer (score 1):

```
apriori.getAllTheRules()
```

returns an Array of FastVectors, but FastVector doesn't have a toString() method to dump its contents as implied by your intentions.  You can extend FastVector and add your own toString() or write a little helper method to dump the contents as desired. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Something like:

```
for(FastVector fastVector : apriori.getAllTheRules())  
  log.debug(fastVector.getRevision()); 
// or whichever attribute you want to show
```

Comment: I dont get your point @belwood. Could you please tell me it in more detail ?

Comment: The default toString() method in an Java object displays the object class and its hash code e.g. from your output:

    [Lweka.core.FastVector;@19a96bae

So look at the example link I provided to add code to print the contents of the array.

Comment: ok i see your point. :) but by checking your link did not alert me. Could you please give me solution. I have been searching this for more than one day now